# How can I get special symbols for my Mii nickname?

Tags: wii-u

For example, I have seen someone with the music note symbol, and I'm confused on how to get these, because I want them.

Comment: Please don't just create new tags.  There's no real reason to create a new tag that's specific to mii creation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Open the Mii Creation.
Under "User Settings" choose "View/Modify user information", skip the body editing and you can change your nickname.

Now, if you press the small keyboard icon (near "z") on the keaboard on screen you can access every special keyboards and characters.

What you're looking for is under **SYMBOL**:

[image]

In the third page you can find the *musical note* character ♪.

[image]